# Why not working this redirect?

Tags: jquery, redirect

I have this site:

[link](http://dizievents.ch/)

I want to create a redirect with this code below:

**CODE JQUERY:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    
window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";
})
```

You tell me what is wrong with this code and how can I restore it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens when you use the code? What is your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a reference to jQuery

Add this to your `head` tag in HTML :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```